# Cannot find symbol variable TYPE_HEADSET_TAP

Tags: java, android, sensors

I am new to Java. Below, I have implemented the following code:

```
package com.epson.moverio.sample.TapSample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.username.internprojectcv.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

static int TYPE_HEADSET_TAP = 0x00002001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEADSET_TAP);
    sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEADSET_TAP) {
        //if tap event occurs, show Toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "tap event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sm != null) {
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
}
```

I am getting compiler error "cannot find symbol variable TYPE_HEADSET_TAP". What could be done to possibly fix this error?

Comment: Did you mean to use either `MainActivity.TYPE_HEADSET_TAP` or just `TYPE_HEADSET_TAP` instead of `Sensor.TYPE_HEADSET_TAP`?

Answer (score -1):

Here list of the sensor types supported by the Android platform

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview
https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types

Search what sensor you need and use the like this:

```
Sensor.TYPE
```